# How long does it take to resign as an elected moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

First off, I understand that the SE team is probably *swamped* right now. If they aren't, I do think that they really should be.

Still, I posted about my resignation as a community moderator on Oct 1 21:39 to 21:40 UTC. I e-mailed Stack Exchange a few minutes before posting that, wherein I requested to resign as a community moderator.

I also later updated the relevant site profiles to indicate that I am resigning as a community moderator.

I have also used the contact form earlier today (Oct 6) to draw staff attention to that e-mail. The contact form doesn't send an acknowledgement that can later be referenced, so I'm not sure of the exact time when I did this (I probably should have kept notes of that, but alas).

In the meantime, a SE employee posted [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/157730) on Oct 3 15:44 UTC.

It's now Oct 6 18:37 UTC. Sure, today's Sunday, but Oct 1 was Tuesday.

I have not yet received as much as an *automated* reply, never mind any reaction from an actual human being.

My previous experience has been that SE staff has been fairly prompt in responding to e-mails. I also see that other moderators have [both resigned and been reinstated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/157730), so they are clearly handling *some* such requests.

How long should I expect to wait before I receive a response?

*Update: My moderator access was revoked on Oct 8 around 11:35 UTC, in response to my original resignation request e-mail, to which I received a reply to that effect from SE.*

Comment: I guess the [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) joke is out of order here ...

Comment: @rene, we do not have six to eight weeks left, I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi *"You resigned from Writing and Worldbuilding, both Monica-moderated before, and SE may have anticipated total defection from these sites, so they may have delayed"* On Workplace, Jane S' diamond has been removed, and Snow's was apparently removed and now restored. So the fact that I was on moderator teams that included Monica certainly can't be the only reason.

Comment: True indeed. What about option 2?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi *"Have you maybe performed any moderation duty"* I have been deliberately avoiding anything that requires diamond moderator powers. Heck, there's been some comments I have wanted to flag as rude/unkind, but if I do that they are deleted immediately (because of the diamond), so I haven't.

Comment: Okay, previous comments removed as obsolete. When you say *deliberately avoiding anything that requires diamond moderator powers* and mention comment flags, I assume you're meaning close votes as well?

Comment: Given that some mods asked to be re-instated they maybe hold back on removing pending diamonds to prevent having to add them back again.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, close votes as well. Basically, I have deliberately done nothing where having a diamond gives more power than not having a diamond. Come to think of it, I have upvoted a few comments this week; I've posted comments, an answer and now this question; but I think that's pretty much it.

Comment: @rene I sent my request before any reinstatement was done. And that doesn't keep anyone at SE from replying with something along the lines of "okay, we've seen this, we'll give it a week just in case you change your mind".

Comment: We're sorry to see you go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The contact form is the recognised method for resigning. Any other method can’t be relied upon to provide the necessary paper trail since it’s not linked to your user profile.

So, officially, you entered your resignation today, on a Sunday.

It takes a few days to process, depending on how busy the SE team is and what their current priorities are.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your mind, as I did, the reverse is true as well.  Use the contact from to request your diamond back -- as long as you resign in good standing.

Considering the volume of requests they get, they responded pretty fast in my case.

YMMV